# RecyclerView Data passing to same Activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a cart program, in activity is simple, there was a recyclerview and a button. In recycler view I can edit its stock.
Now, I want to get that product_name and product_stock from that I've ever clicked and make changes.

Now, when every stock has been clicked, I want click button on activity, so I want that data I've ever clicked on recyclerview stored to array, so that button can do their action / function. Can you guys lead me, how to import data from recyclerview to its activity itself.

It was Android program to do shopping cart, so I click the data in recycler view it stored to activity array.

I don't have any idea how to store that from recyclerview to activity's array.

My expected result, should be, when I click buy button on activity, every changed stock on recyclerview is shown.

Comment: create arraylist of integers that will store the positions and data and button state.from each click store that data in the arraylist and access it.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply implement an interface in your adapter like this for getting the values from clicked position in recycleview.

```
public interface FetchRecyclerViewItems{

    void getItems(String product_name,String product_stock);

    }
```

And simply create a setter method for this interface in adapter like this,

```
private FetchRecyclerViewItems fetchRecyclerViewItems;

public void setFetchRecyclerViewItems(FetchRecyclerViewItems fetchRecyclerViewItems){

this.fetchRecyclerViewItems = fetchRecyclerViewItems;

}
```

Then set the values like this on your click like this in OnBindViewHolder,

```
your_view.setOnClickListener(new View.SetOnClickListener)....{
    ....

    fetchRecyclerViewItems.getItems(product_nameFromPosition,product_stockFromPosition);

}
```

And implement this interface in your activity and you will get the product_name,product_stock values there.
Make sure to initialize the FetchRecyclerViewItems in your activity.